# How to insert id from both tables into pivot table using laravel query builder

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, laravel-5.3

I have three tables in database

1. users
2. locations
3. location_user ***(columns: user_id, location_id)***

I'm fetching records from **locations** table in multiple-drop-down field of user registration form. While filling form user has to select value from drop-down and then submit.

After submitting the form I want to insert data into **users** table. At the same time I also want to insert ***id*** from **users** table into ***user_id*** column of **location_user** and selected ***value*** of locations from drop-down  of user registration form into ***location_id*** column of **location_user** table.

I know how to get this to work using eloquent but I as i mentioned in the question I want to know how to deal with this task using query builder of laravel.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason to use a pivot table here? If you're going to tie a location to a user then just add a `location_id` field to the user table and have a one to many relation (location, user). I don't see any reasoning to use pivot table here unless you want a user to have multiple locations.

Anyway if you follow my advice it becomes easier. But with the current table structure, you need to setup relationships in the respective models. Then on form submit, create the user and attach the location to the user.

User model

```
public function locations()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Location');
}
```

Location model

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User');
}
```

Controller

```
$user = User::create($request->all());
$user->locations()->attach($request->location_id);
```

Comment: I have many to many relationship here not one to many. What I want to achieve here is when I select user from drop-down I want to get all the locations and when I select location from drop-down I want to get all the users. So I need a pivot table here.

Comment: I've done what you've suggested using eloquent already. I'm just curious to know how I could get this to work using query builder using joins.

Answer (score 0):

you must use this code:

```
        $user = new user;
        $user->title = $request->title; // your value
        $user->username = $request->username // your value
        $user->save();
        $user->locations()->attach([1,2]); // or ->attach($location_id);
        /// or $user->locations()->sync([1,2])
```

this is a example for your project when use ORM Eloquent and define relationship in models.
you can attention my example:
model Product

```
class Product extends Model
{
 public function Categories()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Category','product_category','category_id');
    }
}
```

model Category

```
class Category extends Model
{
    public function Products()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Product','product_category','product_id');
    }
}
```

when you want insert in your database you must write this code in your controller

```
        $validated = $request->validated();
        $user = Auth::user();
        $product = new Product;
        $product->title = $request->title;
        $product->off_price = $request->off_price;
        $product->price = $request->price;
        $product->available = $request->available;
        $product->user_id = $user->id;
        $product->save();
        $product->Categories()->attach($request->categories/* this is an array*/);
```

Answer (score -1):

Here, this creates 3 separate queries using the query builder to get to what you want.

```
$user_id = DB::table('users')->insertGetId(
    ['something' => 'something']
);
$location_id = DB::table('locations')->insertGetId(
    ['something' => 'something']
);

DB::table('location_user')->insert(
    ['user_id' => $user_id, 'location_id' => $location_id]
);
```

But Laravel's ORM deals with this, so if you have your models mapped properly, you could do something like this:

```
$location = $user->locations()->create([
    'something' => 'something.',
]);
```

See here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships